# Problems installing OpenCV with Cmake

Tags: cmake, opencv

I'm following a tutorial (https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) to install opencv 3.0 on ubuntu 16, but I've got problems in step 5.2: Run Cmake, until step 5.1 was everything ok.

When I try to execute this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D WITH_TBB=ON \
      -D WITH_V4L=ON \
      -D WITH_QT=ON \
      -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I get this:

```
Parse error in command line argument: -D
Should be: VAR:type=value
CMake Error: No cmake script provided.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I'm very new to ubuntu, I was used to work with opencv on windows.

Comment: Surplus <space>  `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=[option]` ... please do  `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=[option]`

Comment: What is your cmake version (`cmake --version`)? I don't see anything wrong with the command you posted - did you by any chance copy-paste it via an intermediate application such as a word processor program?

Comment: I don't know what was the error, but as incredible as it may seem, I solved it copying the command in the text editor and copying it to the command terminal. It ran after I did it.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this error by removing an extra space after -D

Try running:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -DWITH_TBB=ON \
      -DWITH_V4L=ON \
      -DWITH_QT=ON \
      -DWITH_OPENGL=ON \
      -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
      -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```